# MySQL - PHP variable with date in query does not return any result

Tags: php, mysql, date

Hi I am trying to write a home budget forecast. I got to the point where I'd like to echo out table with dates from today up to certain date (next 2 months for example) and total value for this date.

I put some example data in database already but for some reason none of the records are being returned and all the values are 0 for each date in the table. I did not have a problem with creating same table for "Last Transactions" or "Upcoming Transactions".. Seems that here problem lays in query itself as num_rows is alwasys 0.

```
$currentDate = date('Y-m-d', time());
$endDate = "2019-09-30";
$content = '';
$dayTotal = 0;

while ($currentDate < $endDate) {

    $getForecast_sql = "SELECT value FROM log WHERE date=".$currentDate."";
    $getForecast_result = $conn->query($getForecast_sql);

    if ($getForecast_result === false) {
        echo "Query failed: " .$conn->error;
        return false;
    } else {

        if ($getForecast_result->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row = $getForecast_result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $value = $row['value'];
                $dayTotal += $value;
            }                           
        } 

    $content .= '<tr>
                    <td class="log-date">'  . $currentDate . '</td>
                    <td class="log-desc">'  . $dayTotal . '</td>
                </tr>';

    }
    $currentDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($currentDate . '+1 day'));
}

echo $content;
```

Comment: Quotes missed. Change `WHERE date=".$currentDate.""` to `WHERE date='".$currentDate."'"`

Comment: Make it a habit to use prepared statements, even if the variable is trusted and returned from `date()` function.

Comment: I also would recommend against naming the column `date`. It's allowed, but generally bad practice to use a SQL keyword as a column (or table) name. Use something more unique and descriptive like `transaction_date`.

Comment: OMG thank You! I've spend last few hours on trying to troubleshoot this bit of code xd will do, thank You!

Comment: @RobertJamborski You are welcome :) . Yeah it is hard to troubleshoot because no errors are thrown, that is way I like programs that break with rich informative error messages or error codes more than programs that  break with 'some error happened!' message.